# Conditional CSS based on background color variable

Tags: less

Is it possible to set a color based on the lightness/darkness of a less variable?

Currently I have the following code:

```
li {
    color: darken(@bodyBackground, 10%);
}
```

This works providing `@bodyBackground` is a light color. However if it was a dark color I'd like to use `lighten(@bodyBackground, 10%)`. Is this possible with LESS?

Comment: See [`contrast`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-functions-contrast) function.

Comment: Yes, that does it. Can you add it as an answer please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's [`contrast`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) function, e.g.:

```
li {
    color: contrast(@bodyBackground,
            lighten(@bodyBackground, 13%),
             darken(@bodyBackground, 13%));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can be much smarter than this. You can make a mixin to check the provided color, and perform either a darken or lighten depending on its color:

```
.smart-text-color (@a) when (lightness(@a) >= 50%) {
  // Its a light color return a dark output
  color: darken(@a, 60%);
}
.smart-text-color (@a) when (lightness(@a) < 50%) {
  // Its a dark color return a dark output
  color: lighten(@a, 60%);
}
```

Here is an example mixin, that takes the background color as the variable, and works out what text color to use. Returning either a light or dark output.

http://codepen.io/TristanBrotherton/pen/GwIgx?editors=110

Comment: And how is it smarter than contrast function?

Comment: It's much smarter since you can adjust multiple properties at once.

Comment: @gco, so you simply hardcode your mixin to a particular property set and then have to copy-paste the same code for each new set of properties? With each property duplicated? And how is this smarter?