# LESS setting variable inside mixin

Tags: less

Why is @nav-color not getting set...?

```
@light: #f5f5f5;
@nav-color: #0ff;
@headerbar: #333;  
@dark: #222;
@light: #f5f5f5;

.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) > 50%) {
    @nav-color: @dark;
}
.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) <= 50%) {
    @nav-color: @light;
}
.theme();
```

Comment: It should work if you call the mixin within the selector block and then use the variable mate.

Comment: i need to use the variable globally in different places

Comment: In addition to @Harry's answer below. Beside various options of working this around (you can also remove the default `@nav-color: #0ff;` or put it into another `.theme()` definition) for this particular case you need to notice the [`contrast`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) function (in other words you don't really need such mixin at all).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I have added samples based on your comment to my answer (for completeness sake) mate. Do let me know if you wish to add a separate answer and I will have them removed. By the way, just curious as to how removing `@nav-color: #0ff;` makes it work. Is there a short answer to it? If not, I will probably create a separate question for it.

Comment: All of those are very interesting techniques. I just have to set @nav-color in the global namespace. Not making CSS. Like in my question. So still figuring out the best way.

Comment: @Mike: I don't think I understood your previous comment fully. Can you maybe show us a broader example of what you are trying to achieve by setting the variable in the global namespace? Maybe there are other better alternates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a variable is declared within a namespace or a mixin, it kind of becomes scoped or accessible only within that namespace only and it's value cannot be access outside of the scope.

> [**Reference from Less Website:**](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors) Note that variables declared within a namespace will be scoped to that namespace only and will not be available outside of the scope via the same syntax that you would use to reference a mixin (`#Namespace > .mixin-name`). So, for example, you can't do the following: (`#Namespace > @this-will-not-work`).

**Solution 1:**
One of the options for this particular case would be to use an unnamed namespace (`&`) and call the mixin within it like below:

```
@light: #f5f5f5;
@nav-color: #0ff;
@headerbar: #333;  
@dark: #222;
@light: #f5f5f5;

.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) > 50%) {
    @nav-color: @dark;
}
.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) <= 50%) {
    @nav-color: @light;
}

&{
    .theme();
    div#sample1{
        color: @nav-color;
    }

    div#sample2{
        background-color: @nav-color;
    }
}
```

---

> All the following options are courtesy of [seven-phases-max]'s comment and are added to the answer for completeness sake.

**Solution 2:** Removing the default value for the `@nav-color` variable seems to make the code in question work as-is. This should not create any issues because either one of the `.theme()` mixin's guard conditions would always be matched and hence the variable would always get a value assigned.

```
@light: #f5f5f5;
@headerbar: #333;  
@dark: #222;
@light: #f5f5f5;

.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) > 50%) {
    @nav-color: @dark;
}
.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) <= 50%) {
    @nav-color: @light;
}
.theme();

div#sample1{
    color: @nav-color;
}
```

**Solution 3:** 
A completely different approach to solve this problem would be to use the built-in `contrast()` function mentioned by [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600825/conditional-css-based-on-background-color-variable/21601402#21601402) to totally avoid the mixin and set the variable values directly based on the lightness or darkness of another variable.

---

**Additional Information:**
To further illustrate the point, the below would work fine (though it is not exactly what you are after) and would output the correct color because the value for the `@nav-color` is set within its scope.

```
.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) > 50%) {
    @nav-color: @dark;
    div#sample3{
        border-color: @nav-color;
    }    
}
.theme() when (lightness(@headerbar) <= 50%) {
    @nav-color: @light;
    div#sample3{
        border-color: @nav-color;
    }       
}
```