# How to access a variable outside of a media query?

Tags: css, less

Using Less.

I want to be able to use a variable globally throughout my classes.

Let's say the variable is `@globalPadding;`

I want to set the size of padding using media queries, like this:

```
@media (min-width: @4ColMin) {

    @globalPadding:@4colPadding;
}
```

And in my class, simply use it like this: `padding-top:@globalPadding;`

Is this possible using Less, and if not, are there any o ther techniques I could use to acheive the same thing?

Comment: Typically variables set within a class or mixin is not available outside its scope as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049016/less-setting-variable-inside-mixin/28049494#28049494). I guess the same would be the case here.

Comment: Declare the variable outside of media queries and use it where ever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
@paddingSmallScreen: 20px;
@paddingBigScreen: 40px;

.my-class {
    padding: @paddingSmallScreen;

    @media (min-width: @4ColMin) {
        padding: @paddingBigScreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this creates a class rather than a usable variable, however I believe its the nearest to the required goal that can be acheived at present.