# Get color based on two colors

Tags: less

I want to have a color based on two another colors. So:

1. I have a background color.
2. With `contrast` I get a color for title.
3. Now I want a color for subtitle based on background color and title color.

So finally I could resolve something like:

```
@background-color: dark blue:
@title-color: contrast(@background-color); //white;
@subtitle-color: darken(white, 20%); //Some grey
```

But also:

```
@background-color: light blue:
@title-color: contrast(@background-color); //black;
@subtitle-color: lighten(@title-color, 20%); //Some grey
```

My less file looks like:

```html
@primary-color:#8fc3f7;
body { 
    background: @primary-color; 
    padding: 30px; 
    font: bold 133% "arial", sans-serif;
}
.primary{
    color: contrast(@primary-color);    
}
.secondary{
    color: lighten(contrast(@primary-color), 20%);    
    /*Or...
    color: darken(contrast(@primary-color), 40%);  */  
}
```

And my html file

```html
<div>
    <span class="primary">Primary</span><br>
    <span class="secondary">Secondary</span>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ytfzxts/

I don't know how to get the secondary color based on the two previous results.

Comment: Could you not make use of the threshold parameter? Something like `contrast(@color, lighten(@color, 20%), darken(@color, 20%), 50%);`? I remember seeing a similar question earlier.

Comment: This was the one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600825/conditional-css-based-on-background-color-variable?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Harry, that was it! Do you think I should close this question?

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you want me to VTC, I will do it. Or, if you want to delete the question, please feel free. Just remember that if you have deleted many questions already then VTC would prevent question bans :)