# How to make a colour darker if light, or lighter if dark in LESS

Tags: css, colors, less

Given a colour as input, how do you transform it in LESS so that it becomes darker if it's a light colour, or lighter if it's a dark colour?

For example:

- when the colour is **dark**, the result is something like `darken(@color-input, 10%)`
- when the colour is **light**, the result is something like `lighten(@color-input, 10%)`

Is there any conditional test that can be applied or any [color operation](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations) that would give this result?

Comment: Are you asking how to check if the color-input is a light or dark color?

Comment: @seven-phases-max I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434928/1010492) could be used here indeed

Comment: @GyumFox Not sure why you choose mixin variant since it's 3 times longer than `contrast` doing the same.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I haven't tested the contrast one, I found it harder to understand. Consider posting an answer here to achieve the result I'm after and explain why / how it works. Thanks

Comment: @seven-phases-max I [tested the contrast one here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%5Cn%7B%5Cncolor%3A%20darken(white%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cncolor%3A%20lighten(black%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cndiv%5Cn%7B%5Cncolor%3A%20contrast(white%2C%20lighten(white%2C%2010%25)%2C%20darken(white%2C%2010%25))%3B%5Cncolor%3A%20contrast(black%2C%20lighten(black%2C%2010%25)%2C%20darken(black%2C%2010%25))%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D) and it does the job! Consider posting as an answer :)

Comment: I already voted for closing this as a duplicate - no need to post the same A again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question was correctly identified as a duplicate, but for the sake of answering it **correctly**, here is the right answer (based on [seven-phases-max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21601402/1010492)):

```
contrast(@color-input, lighten(@color-input, 10%), darken(@color-input, 10%));
```

You can see a [working example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22div%5Cn%7B%5Cncolor%3A%20darken(white%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cncolor%3A%20lighten(black%2C%2010%25)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cndiv%5Cn%7B%5Cncolor%3A%20contrast(white%2C%20lighten(white%2C%2010%25)%2C%20darken(white%2C%2010%25))%3B%5Cncolor%3A%20contrast(black%2C%20lighten(black%2C%2010%25)%2C%20darken(black%2C%2010%25))%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D) here.

You can read more about the [contrast function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best answer, but the following code seems to do the trick:

```
mix(@color-input, contrast(@color-input), 90%);
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the neat use of `mix`. Though this way the result is not strictly equal to `darken/lighten`.