# Change color of a hamburger menu depending on the background color

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, background-color, hamburger-menu

I'm working on a polymer project and i want to change the color of my hamburger menu, depending on the background-color, and using the **.css** function by JQuery. For example, if the background-color is blue, i want my button to be white. this is my code :

```
    <paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button id="menuBurger" icon="menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" style="background-color: yellow"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-menu-button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("#menuBurger").css("background-color") === "yellow") {
          $("#menuBurger").css('color', 'red');
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: I recomend use less. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600825/conditional-css-based-on-background-color-variable

Comment: @GeorgeBailey The issue is that the colors doesn't change, and also i think that the problem is that i can't get access to my elements (like paper-menu-button) in Polymer.

Comment: @Rakowu Thanks for replying, i will check that.

Comment: I am not sure about the usage of jQuery and Polymer together.. `$('#element')` basically means `document.getElementById('element')`, but if here you're already inside a custom element that wouldn't work.. as a first test you can try to see if changing that line to `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('menuBurger').style.color = 'red';` changes anything (or what the reference to the current element would be, this seems a bit out of context)

Comment: It finally worked with this : `var fond = this.$.menuBurger.style.backgroundColor ;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare that `background-color` with the corresponsing `rgb` value as `css("background-color")` is giving the `rgb` value of `yellow`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#menuBurger").css("background-color") === "rgb(255, 255, 0)") {
    $("#menuBurger").css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<paper-menu-button>
      <paper-icon-button id="menuBurger" icon="menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" style="background-color: yellow">ICON</paper-icon-button>
      <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-menu-button>
```

> jQuery returns the element color in RGB format

But if you do not want to do that then you can assign a hex color `#ffff00` which corresponds to `yellow` and then create a custom function that will convert `rgb` to `hex` value as in `rgb2hex`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function rgb2hex(orig){
   var rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g,'').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/i);
   return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : orig;
  }

  var burgerbackground = $("#menuBurger").css("background-color");
  if (rgb2hex(burgerbackground) === "#ffff00") {
    $("#menuBurger").css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<paper-menu-button>
  <paper-icon-button id="menuBurger" icon="menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" style="background-color: #ffff00">ICON</paper-icon-button>
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-menu-button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It makes me this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". I think it's a more general problem : i can't get access to my elements (like the paper-menu-button).

Answer (score 0):

Simpy add a div with width, height as zero. Set it's background to the background color you want to compare with and then do this way

```
 if ($("#menuBurger").css("background-color") == $("#test").css("background-color"))
```

Here is the snipped

```js
var testColor = "yellow"
$("#test").css('background-color','yellow')
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if ($("#menuBurger").css("background-color") == $("#test").css("background-color")) {
          $("#menuBurger").css('color', 'red');
        }
      });
```

```css
#menuBurger{
background-color : "yellow"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<paper-menu-button>
  <paper-icon-button id="menuBurger" icon="menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" style="background-color: #ffff00">ICON</paper-icon-button>
  <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-menu-button>
```